# Как убрать отображение ссылок на соседние страницы WordPress тема Twenty Twelve

Tags: php, wordpress, ссылки

**Как убрать отображение ссылок на соседние страницы?**

Чтобы там вообще ничего не было. А то отображает ссылки на страницы из других рубрик.

Тема WordPress Twenty Twelve. (*Сам уже два дня мучаюсь без толку*).

[image: Стрелочками я обозначил эти ненавистные ссылки]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не стоит вносить правки в тему, потому что при обновлении темы они слетят.

Создайте [дочернюю тему](https://wp-kama.ru/id_6235/dochernie-temy-wordpress.html). Скопируйте файл `wp-content/themes/twentytwelve/single.php` в `wp-content/themes/ваша-тема/single.php`. В этом скопированном файле удалите строки

```
<nav class="nav-single">
    <h3 class="assistive-text"><?php _e( 'Post navigation', 'twentytwelve' ); ?></h3>
    <span class="nav-previous"><?php previous_post_link( '%link', '<span class="meta-nav">' . _x( '&larr;', 'Previous post link', 'twentytwelve' ) . '</span> %title' ); ?></span>
    <span class="nav-next"><?php next_post_link( '%link', '%title <span class="meta-nav">' . _x( '&rarr;', 'Next post link', 'twentytwelve' ) . '</span>' ); ?></span>
</nav><!-- .nav-single -->
```

Answer (score 0):

В файле `index.php` темы найдите и удалите строчку

```
<?php twentytwelve_content_nav( 'nav-below' ); ?>
```